# allocating and returning a 2d array pointer where rows and columns are runtime parameters

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have written a simple code where i want to allocate a 2d array in C++.The rows(m) and columns(n) would be provided by user at run time.
So  the function func should return a pointer to the allocated array.Below is the code however i am getting compilation error .

```
int** func(int **arr,int m,int n){
arr=new int *[m];
for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
    arr[i]= new int arr[n];
    }
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
  int **arr;
  arr=func(arr,4,10)
}
```

Comment: run time sized array == `std::vector`.  If you can use it you should.

Comment: Which compilation error do you get?

Comment: You missed a `;` at the end of `arr=func(arr,4,10)`. `arr[i]= new int arr[n];` should be `arr[i]= new int[n];`

Comment: **Beware**: this is an array of pointers and **not** a 2D arrays. Even if accessed the same way, they are different animals. [more refs here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16390020/3545273)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
arr[i] = new int[n];
```

instead of

```
arr[i]= new int arr[n];
```

and also, put semicolon after the function call,

```
arr=func(arr,4,10);
```

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int** func(int **arr,int m,int n)
{
        arr = new int*[m];
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
                arr[i] = new int[n];
        }
        return arr;
}

int main()
{
        int **arr;
        arr=func(arr,4,10);
}
```

Comment: ohh shit .. how can i give variable name in the new operator!! .. Thanks a lot for pointing out.